# Targeting logic for 1.000.000 units army

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am making an army fight for my website [armyfight](http://www.armyfight.com). There can be fights of million units. I am looking for better unit targeting. in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mansim/a2cmmr1m/18/) is an example.

```
var enemy = {
    2: { 
        3: {}  // object inside with unit data
    },
      5: { 
        6: {} 
    }
}

var ally = {
    4: { 
        3: {}
    }
}

function unit_searches_for_target(y, x) {
    var closest_y   = iterate_Y(y);
    var unit_target = iterate_X(closest_y, x);
  return unit_target;
}

// Searches for closest target at Y axis
function iterate_Y(y) {
    if (_.has(target, y)) {
        return y;
    } else {
      var y = parseInt(y);
        for (var i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
            // If y == 4, it checks 4+1=5 (positive side)
            if (_.has(target, String(y + i))) {
                return (y+i);
            // Else if y == 4, it checks 4-1=3 (negative side)
            } else if (_.has(target, String(y - i))) {
                return (y-i);
            }
        }
    }
    // if didn't find anything, just returns same y as given
    return y;
};

// Searches for closest target at X axis
function iterate_X(y, x) {
    if (_.has(target[y], x)) {
        return {y: y, x: x};
    } else {
      var x = parseInt(x);
        for (var i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
            // If x == 4, it checks 4+1=5 (positive side)
            if (_.has(target[y], String(x + i))) {
            return {y: y, x: x + i};
            // Else if x == 4, it checks 4-1=3 (negative side)
            } else if (_.has(target[y], String(x - i))) {
              return {y: y, x: x - i};
            }
        }
    }
    // if didn't find anything, just returns same x as given
    return {y: y, x: x};
};
```

Here first i iterate on Y axis, later on X axis. But on different army positions it gives wrong results.

 
In this example, units are looking for targets by simply iterating. It is not very good for a huge army fight of million units.
Best would be to iterate like here, when iteration process is much faster leading to first-hit success:

```
function iterate_X(y, x) {
  return _.find(enemy[y], function (value, key) { return parseInt(key) >= x });
}
```

But this iteration works only 0..100, or 99..100, but not 100..0, so i can't iterate objects in reverse mode.
 So if ally is `{5: {10: {}, 99: {}}` and enemy is at `{5: {100: {}}}`, enemy unit would find closest ally as [5, 10] instead of [5, 99]. If it would be an array iterating backwards from 100 to 0, so it would be first-hit success. But then i have problems with assotiative array, can it be reverse-iterated? 
Any suggestions please on structure? Maybe change units structure from objects to arrays or mix?  But then I have problems with associative arrays. I am looking for an explanation or example about the structure and for a faster iteration for units targeting.
And i am also looking for websites, where i could ask these heavy logic questions? I have more of them.

Comment: If your targeting is at all related to distance, you should consider storing your objects in a quad tree, or some similarly gridded model. That way you only ever have to test objects against relatively nearby objects, and the lookup is O(1) with only local iteration.

Comment: Moreover I'd also consider to group units in *groups*. Millions are...a lot for a Javascript game

Comment: Thanks for answers. I am seriously thinking about Adriano's answer, about grouping armies. Thats sounds a good idea. Then one army of 100 units can just iterate over all other armies of 100 units and just simply find closest enemy army. Then whole army could move towards the nearest army. Sounds good for me, maybe better than solo-unit targeting.

Comment: I have readed about quad tree and it seems it would be too much scanning and calculation in this way, never first-shot target find like i have now. Because always first target search is when army initiated and relatively very far away form enemies. Thats why looking around in quad tree would take a lot of steps.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid funcions like "find" for performance reasons, and use some kind of indexed access instead.

For example, and can put your units into hash:

Keys of this hash could be a string xcoord+":"+ycord

Values of this hash could be hashes of your objects, keyed by some unique unit ID.
So, then you can search neighbors of a unit by just checking what is in current cell and surrounding 8 cells

I tried code below, it finds all neighbors of all 1M units in under 1 sec.

```
    var units = {}

for(var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
    var idx = x+":"+y;
    if(!units[idx])
        units[idx] = {};

    units[idx][i] = {
        id: i,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        //... other attributes of your unit
    };
};

// find neighbours for each unit;

console.log('Started lookups');
var start = new Date().getTime();

var keys = Object.keys(units);
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var neighbours = findNeighbours(units[keys[i]]);
}

var finish = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Finished lookups in '+(finish-start));

function findNeighbours(unit) {
    var res = [];
    // check who is in all 9 cells
    // x     x     x
    // x    unit   x
    // x     x     x
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
            var idx = (unit.x+i-1)+":"+(unit.y+j-1);
            var unitsInCell = units[idx];
            if(unitsInCell) {
                var keys = Object.keys(unitsInCell);
                for(var j = 0; j<keys.length; j++)
                    res.push(unitsInCell[keys[j]]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. The neightbours in 1 cell is possible to find in faster ways. But i am looking for a far-away target, that unit should move towards it. There are many far-away units on many different positions in map and i need to find closest, and in fastest way. Imagine, if unit finds the target  and moves towards it, then on every move it scans only 3 cells forwards, dont even need to scan backwards. And when the unit attacks target from behind, and if target itself have no targe,t the unit makes the target targeting this unit. Thats why its enough not to scan backwards.